# Splunk search by given timestamp not the time of ingestion to splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation, splunk-dashboard

Is it possible to connect the timestamp given in the Data set to the Splunk date picker.

[image: Here is what mean]

Comment: So basically the data has its own Timestamp
And i want to use that

Answer (score 1):

Every event has a least one timestamp associated with it, `_time`, and that timestamp is what is connected to the time picker.  If you want to use a different field then you'll have to filter the events yourself.  Start by converting the Timestamp field into epoch form using the `strptime` function.  Then test that value against the info_min_time and info_max_time fields provided by the `addinfo` command.  That should yield events within the time picker window.

````
index=foo
```Get the time range of this search```
| addinfo 
```Convert Timestamp into epoch form```
| eval ts=strptime(Timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%1N")
```Keep events within the selected time window```
| where (ts>info_min_time AND ts<=info_max_time)
````